# No code is generated when creating new module in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android tv development and my question is how I can use the codes of app module in the tv module because all of them are unknown for the tv module? Also, I try to add the app module in the dependencies of the tv module by this code in the Gradle file

```
implementation project(':app')
```

but I got the following error :
dependent features configured but no package id was set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to share code between mobile and TV apps is to create a separate library module that you include in the dependencies for both.